# Expected ' ' to be an inline constant. Java -> Groovy

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I am using a custom annotation in my groovy script:

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface ScriptManifest {

/**
 * Sets the scripts publicity mode.
 * @return ScriptMode
 */
ScriptMode mode();

/**
 * Sets the type of script we are using.
 * @return ScriptType
 */
Class<? extends ScriptContext>[] type();

/**
 * Sets the name of the script.
 * @return name
 */
String script_name();

/**
 * Sets the author of the script.
 * @return author
 */
String author();

}
```

Creating the test script, my IntelliJ shows the error " Expected 'ScriptMode.PUBLIC' to be an inline constant" and same for TestContext.class. The script functions and runs fine I just am not sure as to why it is showing this for me as if it is an error.

```
@ScriptManifest(mode = ScriptMode.PUBLIC, type = TestContext.class, script_name = "Test", author = "Jake")
class Test extends Script {

@Override
void prepare() {
    println "no" + getName()
}

}
```

Comment: well, for me idea shows that inline error when `mode = ScriptMode.PUBLIC` is changed to `mode: ScriptMode.PUBLIC`, otherwise, it works fine.

Comment: Strange, it works fine, compiling/running its just showing that there is an error for some reason. [Picture of error](http://puu.sh/o7ua6/e163d2664c.png)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue doing the following: I was trying to compile it in my Maven project with the javac, I added a new groovy module and compiled it with groovyc and it works fine now.