# IntelliJ appears to be using javac instead of groovyc for groovy files?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

I have Java experience but I'm new to Groovy.  Also, I'm used to doing my Java work in Eclipse but I've been asked to switch to IntelliJ so I have done that.  The project I inherited was checked out from a GitHub repository that I know is sound since it passes the deployment tool's checks (CircleCI), so I'm assuming the issue is in my IntelliJ configuration, which I believe is outside the GitHub tree so I have to recreate the proper configuration settings myself.

I have IntelliJ, Java, and Groovy installed on my Ubuntu Linux box.  Version details:

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Groovy 2.4.9J VM: 1.8.0_25 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
Java 8 - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2
Build #IU-172.3317.76, built on July 15, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b5 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 3.13.0-123-generic

I have also enabled the auto-import of Gradle/Maven projects.

Unfortunately I'm getting an error flagged on all the constants in the groovy (".groovy") script files.  For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lookup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String authentication(@RequestParam(name = "hub.mode") String mode,
                      @RequestParam(name = "hub.challenge") String challenge,
                      @RequestParam(name = "hub.verify_token") String token)
```

This error message shows for the constant **RequestMethod.GET** the following error:

```
Expected RequestMethod.GET to be an inline constant
```

In this SO post the author says he was having the same problem because he was using **javac** instead of **groovyc** to compile his groovy files.

[Expected ' ' to be an inline constant. Java -> Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435245/expected-to-be-an-inline-constant-java-groovy)

What do I need to do make sure IntelliJ is using groovyc instead of javac?

Also, under the Project Structure dialog, *Project* selection, the *Project SDK* field shows "no SDK" selected and the drop-down box for selecting an SDK is empty (i.e. - the only available choice is ).  This seems like a problem to me.  If it is, how do I configure it?

Comment: Check out Settings -> Build, Execution, and Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler. then there should be a drop down for "Use Compiler" what happens if you try switching that to groovy? I would make this my answer, but I am not sure if this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but for anyone new coming through..

You can:

1. Go to Settings/Build, Execution, Deployment/Compiler, and under Java Compiler you can select Groovy/Eclipse (if you have groovy-eclipse-batch jar)
2. Go to the same location, and under Compiler there is now a Groovy Compiler option where you can put your Groovyc settings.